# When should I use 'open' event in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, events

I'm learning Node.js and while touching events and streams topic I encountered this example:

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

http
  .createServer((req, res) => {
    const fileStream = fs.createReadStream('./some-data.txt', 'utf8');
    
    fileStream.on('open', () => {
      fileStream.pipe(res);
    });

    fileStream.on('error', (err) => {
      res.end(err);
    });
  })
  .listen(5000);
```

While I understand the logic behind this code (server transfers some big data in chunks with the help of streams), I don't understand the benefit of using 'open' event.
Same code, where I just pipe data from read stream into write one (`res` object) right after creating `fileStream` without listening to 'open', produces exactly same result. What is the difference and in which cases should I listen to 'open'?

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

http
  .createServer((req, res) => {
    const fileStream = fs.createReadStream('./some-data.txt', 'utf8');

    fileStream.pipe(res);

    fileStream.on('error', (err) => {
      res.end(err);
    });
  })
  .listen(5000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case, it does not really make any difference if you use the `open` event or not. If the file does not exist, the `error` event will be emitted anyway and you will send it via `res.end(err.message)` (not that `res.end(err)` fails because the `err` is an object).

The `open` event tells us that the stream is `open` so that we can handle that in the code.

Comment: what is difference between open and read? Is even read an event?